# Having trouble setting class path

Tags: java, classpath

I've tried to look up other questions on people having the same issue, and I re-read the documentation, but this has been buggine me all day

I have Coffee.Java , which is located in C:\Learning Java\209\CoffeeProject\machine

---

```
package machine;
public class Coffee {    
    private static long counter = 0;
    private final long id = counter++;
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + " "+ id;
    }
}
```

and Latte, which is just

```
//Latte.java
package machine;
public class Latte extends Coffee{}
```

and I'm trying to set path by doing

```
java -classpath C:\Learning Java\209\CoffeeProject machine.Coffee
```

but it's giving me the error

Could not find or load main class Java\209\CoffeeProject

I have been going off of this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

Edit: I tried the quotes, and it works. Thanks. Now it says main method not found, and there isn't one, but it's just set up so I can extend off of it, and that's how it is in the book. Do I have to have the last program with the main that all this is set up for before I can even do the Classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
java -classpath "C:\Learning Java\209\CoffeeProject" machine.Coffee
```

The space in "Learning Java" causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `classpath` option (or other command line options for that matter) cannot contain spaces without enclosing the entire classpath in quotes. So try `-cp "C:\Learning Java\209\CoffeeProject"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Quotes in classpath if spaces are found

As a rule of thumb, if you have spaces in your `classpath`, always make sure to surround those with quotes as explained [here](http://www.digizol.com/2006/12/setting-java-classpath-option-with.html).